# Mongoose throws error on adding Date in Schema and not passing it to the creation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My schema looks like this

```js
const user = {
   usedAt:{type:Date},
   name: String
}
```

when tried creating the user with

```json
const create = await new userDB({name:"santhosh"}).save()
```

throws error as

```
user validation failed: usedAt: Cast to date failed for valie "Invalid Date" (type Date) at path "usedAt"
```

not sure what i'm missing and also I'm not looking to add default date value as well.

Comment: If you don't want a default date value, what _do_ you want? Also, with that schema and that code, you shouldn't be getting an error. Something is missing from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit field like this;

```js
usedAt:{
  type:Date,
  default: new Date()
}
```

Comment: i don't want default date value

Comment: @santhosh So, what do you want? If you don't want date to be a required field, put ' required : false '

Comment: by default mongoose required are false

Comment: actually my question is wrong.... when i checked the code i was passing Invalida Date in parametter

Comment: @santhosh if that's the case, please close your question.

Comment: ok closed the question